# Unity Pink Splash Screen on Mobile Device

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, game-development, splash-screen

I have a pink splash screen after building and testing on my mobile device. The pink screen only appears on the splash screen while the rest of the game is okay.

I tried to reset the graphics in `Edit > Project Settings > Graphics` but still nothing.

I also tried to disable Multithreading Rendering in the player settings located at Other Settings but still no changes.

One of the biggest challenges is that even after doing so, it would require i build the game and test it out in the mobile device again to check if it works.

The splash screen works perfectly fine in the unity editor.

I'm using Unity 2021.3.4f1. Concerning URP/HDRP, I have not enabled such.

Comment: sounds like a bug .. have you tried [reporting](https://unity.com/releases/editor/qa/bug-reporting) it as such?

Comment: No, I haven't. Let me do so

Comment: It seems it was a bug. I solved it by Upgrading the unity version to LTS version 2022.3.20f11